# Adding new objects to an ArrayList using a constructor

Tags: java, object, arraylist, addition

I have to make a small app as an class exercise which simulates an mobile phone which is able to add and list contacts.

In the main I have to create a new mobile phone by its brand and to add new contacts in it. How can I make an ArrayList which stores the contacts and add them in the List as it follows ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Phone phone = new GalaxyS6();//should compile

    phone.addContact("id", "phoneNumber", "firstName", "lastName");
```

Comment: What is the language used?

Comment: Java is the language.

Comment: What do you mean by make "make an ArrayList which stores the contacts and add them in the List as it follows " ? Can you be more specific, so that its easy to answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the objects to the arraylist,
Create the arraylist of your class type and you can add it something like this,

```
   ArrayList<Phone> phoneList = new ArrayList<>();
   phoneList.add(new phone("id", "phoneNumber", "firstName", "lastName"));
```