# How to add multiple values in add method of array?

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist

I am trying to add multiple values to an array, but it returns a cannot resolve error. Is there any way or work-around here?

```
for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : hash.entrySet()) {
          String key = entry.getKey();
          String value = entry.getValue();

          if(typePHP.equals("TARGET")) {
              message += key + " " + value + "t\n";
           }else {
              message += key + " " + value + "r\n";
           }
          array.add(Integer.parseInt(key),value,typePHP,gamePHP);
          //Heres the error.
    }
```

Here's the error:`Cannot resolve method 'add(int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)'`

> I need the single element to store 4 values at once and have an output like {109,40, TYPE, GAME};

Comment: please post full error log

Comment: please check again @Fartab

Comment: The error you posted says that `array` does not have `add` method. what is the type of `array`? please mention its declaration.

Comment: `ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList <>();` @Fartab, I can add values to it but I can only add 1 value at a time, I need it to be 4 values at once.

Comment: you need to use 'push', like: array.push(item1, item2, ..., itemX), the add-method doen't work

Comment: There's no push method for it @sultan95

Comment: use `addAll` method

Comment: Just call `add` method 4 times, or you can use `addAll`

Comment: what is type of `array`? Your requirement is custom obj so you can create custom object and store in arrayList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use addAll in this way:

```
array.addAll(Arrays.asList( key,value,typePHP,gamePHP) );
```

**UPDATE**:
You need a 2d array, based on this sentence `I need the single element to store 4 values at once and have an output like {109,40, TYPE, GAME};`

So, try this:

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> array2d = new ArrayList<>();
    array2d.add(new ArrayList<String>() {{
        add("109");
        add("40");
        add("TYPE");
        add("GAME");
    }});
```

In your case, there should be something like this:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> array2d = new ArrayList<>();

for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : hash.entrySet()) {
      String key = entry.getKey();
      String value = entry.getValue();

      if(typePHP.equals("TARGET")) {
          message += key + " " + value + "t\n";
       }else {
          message += key + " " + value + "r\n";
       }

      array2d.add(new ArrayList<String>() {{
        add(key);
        add(value);
        add(typePHP);
        add(gamePHP);
    }});
}
```

Comment: This returns it as a single element, I need it to only contain 4 string values at once in 1 element.

Comment: I've updated the solution to contain 4 string values at once in 1 element

Comment: Your updated answer works perfectly, thank you! I also accepted it as correct answer

Answer (score 2):

First, ensure that your ArrayList is currently storing an object with a constructor of (String a, String b, String c). When you call array.add(new Item(a, b, c), Java needs to match that to an existing method.

```
public class Item {
public Item(String a, String b, String c) {
        // initialize your object's variables here in the constructor
    }

}
```

Then, you have to use new when you're creating a new object using add().

```
array.add(new Item(a, b, c));
```

See this from Java: [Adding new objects to an ArrayList using a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53381965/adding-new-objects-to-an-arraylist-using-a-constructor)

And this reference from Oracle about constructors: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create Custom object of your choice member

```
public class Item {

    private int key;
    private  String value;
    private String typePHP;
    private String gamePHP;

    public Item(int key, String value, String typePHP, String gamePHP) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
        this.typePHP = typePHP;
        this.gamePHP = gamePHP;
    }

    public int getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(int key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getTypePHP() {
        return typePHP;
    }

    public void setTypePHP(String typePHP) {
        this.typePHP = typePHP;
    }

    public String getGamePHP() {
        return gamePHP;
    }

    public void setGamePHP(String gamePHP) {
        this.gamePHP = gamePHP;
    }
}
```

Now you can use like

```
ArrayList<Item> itemArray = new ArrayList <>();

for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : hash.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    String value = entry.getValue();

    if(typePHP.equals("TARGET")) {
        message += key + " " + value + "t\n";
    }else {
        message += key + " " + value + "r\n";
    }
    itemArray.add(new Item(Integer.parseInt(key),value,typePHP,gamePHP));
}
```